TimeoutError: Timeout in AWS EC2 Target Groups
When I am trying to view the previous target groups created or when I am trying to create new target groups I am getting TimeoutError: Timeout


I want to create an Elastic Load Balancer for an EC2 instance to forward the traffic I need a target group and I am unable to create one. Are there any other options?
Also my billing and cost management page is not opening I have tried clearing Cache as well


Using an other browser resolved the issue

Could you elaborate which browser/version was causing the issue and what browser/version works for you? Did you tried to unload all extensions from your previous browser, as it could be not the browser itself as your config of the browser
